# To take screenshot of content and show in thumbnail as file preview while saving the file of custom file extension using c# wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

To keep it simple and quick,

1. I launch a notepad (File extension .txt).
2. I have written something inside opened notepad file.
3. I am saving the notepad file with any filename (Say Test) in custom
   file extension [(File extension .dod) - So File Name would be -
   Test.dod]
4. Once it is saved on system as Test.dod, it shows default window
   provided icon for Test.dod file.
5. My requirement is - Instead of default window provided icon for
   Test.dod, I want to display the screenshot of the content present in
   the file just before it is saved, as file icon or in thumbnail.

A real time perfect example would be: Any jpg image file or mpeg video file, will show the content of image or video in their thumbnail when we choose "Extra Large Icons" or "Large Icons" in "view" tab of any folder. The same feature I want to implement for Test.dod file.

So far, I have tried a couple of approaches to update the registry manually however I am looking for simple solution using C# WPF.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
namespace ThumbnailDisplay
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private const string IMAGE_PATH = @"E:\Rahul\CSharp\DisplayThumbnail\ThumbnailDisplay\Image\Flower.JPG";
        private const string TITLE = "Sample Application";
        private const string CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE = "File is Copied in .dod format!";
        private const string INPUT_PATH = @"E:\Rahul\CSharp\DisplayThumbnail\ThumbnailDisplay\Icons\Add.png";
        private const string OUTPUT_PATH = @"E:\Rahul\CSharp\DisplayThumbnail\ThumbnailDisplay\GeneratedTextFile\";
        private const string GENERATED_ICO_FILE_PATH = @"E:\Rahul\CSharp\DisplayThumbnail\ThumbnailDisplay\GeneratedTextFile\ScreenCapture.ico";
        private const string GENERATED_PNG_FILE_PATH = @"E:\Rahul\CSharp\DisplayThumbnail\ThumbnailDisplay\GeneratedTextFile\ScreenCapture.png";
        private const int MAXIMUM_PIXEL = 40;
        private const string SCREEN_CAPTURE = "ScreenCapture";
        private const string ICO_EXTENSION = ".ico";
        private const string PNG_EXTENSION = ".png";
        private string _sampleFileLocation = @"E:\Rahul\CSharp\DisplayThumbnail\ThumbnailDisplay\SampleTextFile\Dummy.txt";
        private string _generatedFileCopy = @"E:\Rahul\CSharp\DisplayThumbnail\ThumbnailDisplay\GeneratedTextFile\Test.dod";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetThumbnailImage();
        }

        private void SetThumbnailImage()
        {
            this.Title = TITLE;
            Uri thumbNail = new Uri(IMAGE_PATH, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(thumbNail);
        }

        private System.Drawing.Size GetThumbnailSize(Image originalImage)
        {
            double factor;
            int originalWidth = originalImage.Width;
            int originalHeight = originalImage.Height;
            if (originalWidth > originalHeight)
            {
                factor = (double)MAXIMUM_PIXEL / originalWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                factor = (double)MAXIMUM_PIXEL / originalHeight;
            }
            return new System.Drawing.Size((int)(originalWidth * factor), (int)(originalHeight * factor));
        }

        private void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(_sampleFileLocation))
            {
                if (File.Exists(_generatedFileCopy))
                {
                    File.Delete(_generatedFileCopy);
                }
                if(File.Exists(GENERATED_ICO_FILE_PATH))
                {
                    File.Delete(GENERATED_ICO_FILE_PATH);
                }
                UIElement element = scrollViewer.Content as UIElement;

                var bitmap = new Bitmap(OUTPUT_PATH + SCREEN_CAPTURE + ICO_EXTENSION);
                var iconHandle = bitmap.GetHicon();
                var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(iconHandle);
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(GENERATED_ICO_FILE_PATH, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

                Uri path = new Uri(GENERATED_ICO_FILE_PATH);
                CaptureScreen(element, path);
                File.Copy(_sampleFileLocation, _generatedFileCopy);
                MessageBox.Show(CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        public void CaptureScreen(UIElement source, Uri destination)
        {
            try
            {
                double Height, renderHeight, Width, renderWidth;

                Height = renderHeight = source.RenderSize.Height;
                Width = renderWidth = source.RenderSize.Width;

                //Specification for target bitmap like width/height pixel etc.
                RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)renderWidth, (int)renderHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                //creates Visual Brush of UIElement
                VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(source);

                DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
                using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
                {
                    //draws image of element
                    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), new System.Windows.Point(Width, Height)));
                }
                //renders image
                renderTarget.Render(drawingVisual);

                //PNG encoder for creating PNG file
                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(destination.LocalPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WPF Code is:

Comment: Show us what you have try so far and what is your actual problem. You should know that StackOverflow is _not_ a do-my-job service.

Comment: As far as I know, icons are global for file types and not individual files. You could do some some hacky stuff like make a bitmap screenshots and append all your data to the end of it so that windows thinks its a bitmap and displays the thumbnail, but in reality the file will also contain your data. Another hacky way would be to treat it like an executable since they get their own icons.

Comment: Thanks John for your view. I have uploaded the sample application code here, though this code will not updating registry dynamically however manually I can achieve it. I am looking for simple solution using C# WPF.